# position or getAdapterPosition error in method onBindViewHolder while developing app

Tags: java, android, firebase

Hi Guys getting an error "Do not treat position as fixed; only use immediately and call holder.getAdapterPosition() to look it up later"

'''

```
 public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull WallpaperViewHolder holder,  int 
    position) {
    Glide.with(context).load(list.get(position)).into(holder.imageView);
    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent=new Intent(context,FullImageActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("image",list.get(position));
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

'''
```

Comment: use `holder.getBindingAdapterPosition()` instead of `position`

Comment: you can also use `holder.getAdapterPosition()` instead of position

Comment: I used holder.getAdapterPosition()
 but getting this error 2022-04-26 22:25:18.696 7376-7376/com.example.mywallpaper E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
2022-04-26 22:25:20.135 7376-7376/com.example.mywallpaper E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.mywallpaper, PID: 7376
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Argument must not be null
        at com.bumptech.glide.util.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:29)
        at com.bumptech.glide.util.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:23)